# Maximising the argument of $\sin and \cos$, given a linear relation between them

Tags: trigonometry, substitution

Here is a problem I have been struggling with for a while,

If $$4\sin\theta \cos\phi+2\sin\theta+2\cos\phi+1=0$$

where $\theta,\phi\in[0,2\pi]$,

find the largest possible value of $(\theta+\phi)$

I have no idea how to do it, i tried substituting $r\sin\theta=a$ and $r\cos\phi=b$
but this did not worked out effectively.
Any other approach for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

We have $$4\cos\phi\sin\theta+2\cos\phi+2\sin\theta+1=(2\cos\phi+1)(2\sin\theta+1)$$

Use [all sin tan cos rule](https://www.math-only-math.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule.html#:%7E:text=What%20is%20all%20sin%20tan,the%20fourth%20quadrant%20are%20positive.)